# Laravel doesntHave with callback said object of class Closure could not be converted to string

Tags: eloquent, laravel-7

i want to write a query like that:

```
$schedule = Schedule::doesntHave('orders', function ($q) {
            $q->where('status', Order::STATUS_CANCEL);
        })
```

and laravel throw exception that said:

```
"Object of class Closure could not be converted to string"
```

can you help me if you faced this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution

We should send second parameter to query for can translate query; My query should be like this:

```
$schedule = Schedule::doesntHave('orders', 'and', function ($q) {
            $q->where('status', Order::STATUS_CANCEL);
        });
```